# Merging all queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql

I have a 2 column table that I need to query against another 2 column table. I have multiple queries to determine:

1. if column 1 exists
2. if column 2 exists
3. if the combination of column 1 and 2 exists (if not, get the associated values of each one)

Sample tables:

```
create table tblSource (col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20))
create table myTable (colA varchar(20), colB varchar(20))

insert into tblSource (col1, col2) 
values ('foo1','bar1'), ('foo2','bar2'), ('foo3','bar3'),('foo4','bar4');

insert into myTable (colA, colB) 
values ('foo1','bar3'), ('foo2','bar2'), ('foo5','bar3'),('foo6','bar6');
```

I want to show that in `myTable` ('foo1','bar3') exists separately, but their combination does not and foo1 is associated with bar1 and bar3 is associated with foo1 in `tblSource`. What is the most concise query to achieve this?

I have written simple individual queries like the following, but I think there should be a better way to achieve this.

This returns which of the colA values do or do not exist in `tblSource`. I have to do the same thing for colB and then for the combination.

One last note that I am using Azure SQL database, however, I have to use ADO to run the queries from Excel.

```
SELECT col1, colA 
FROM myTable 
LEFT JOIN tblSource ON myTable.colA = tblSource.col1
```

**Edit:**

The expected result should be something like this:

```
1. ('foo1','bar3'): both exist, but not associated, foo1-bar1 , foo3-bar3
2. ('foo2','bar2'): both exist and associated
3. ('foo5','bar3'): colB exist only, NULL, foo3-bar3
4. ('foo6','bar6'): None exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
SELECT 
    colA, colB, 
    CASE 
        WHEN C0 > 0 THEN 'both exist and associated'
        WHEN C0 = 0 AND C1 = 0 AND C2 = 0 THEN 'None exist'
        WHEN C0 = 0 AND C1 > 0 AND C2 = 0 THEN 'colA exist only'
        WHEN C0 = 0 AND C1 = 0 AND C2 > 0 THEN 'colB exist only'
        WHEN C0 = 0 AND C1 > 0 AND C2 > 0 THEN 'both exist, but not associated'
    END
FROM 
    ( SELECT T.colA, T.colB, 
        COUNT(*) C
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN T.colA = S.col1 AND T.colB = S.col2 THEN 1 END) C0
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN T.colA = S.col1 THEN 1 END) C1
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN T.colB = S.col2 THEN 1 END) C2
      FROM myTable T
            LEFT JOIN tblSource S ON T.colA = S.col1 or T.colB = S.col2
      GROUP BY T.colA, T.colB
    ) AS GRP
```

Result:

```
colA                 colB                 
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------
foo2                 bar2                 both exist and associated
foo1                 bar3                 both exist, but not associated
foo5                 bar3                 colB exist only
foo6                 bar6                 None exist
```

Comment: this method fails when same/duplicate col2's are associated with uniquecol1's e.g. try these: `insert into tblSource (col1,col2) values('foo1','bar1'), ('foo2','bar2'), ('foo3','bar3'),('foo4','bar4'),('foo6','bar1');
insert into myTable (colA,colB) values('foo1','bar3'), ('foo2','bar2'), ('foo5','bar3'),('foo6','bar6'),('foo4','bar7'),('foo6','bar1');`

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to just use separate columns to contain the information, but you can represent this as strings -- with a big `case` expression.

Here is a method:

```
select col1, col2, max(in_s) as in_s, max(in_m) as in_m,
       (case when max(in_s) = 1 and max(in_m) = 1
             then 'in both and associated'
             when max(in_s) = 1 and
                  max(max(in_m)) over (partition by col1) = 1 and
                  max(max(in_m)) over (partition by col2) = 1 
             then 'in both, both not associated'
             when max(in_m) = 1 and
                  max(max(in_s)) over (partition by col1) = 1 and
                  max(max(in_s)) over (partition by col2) = 1 
             then 'in both, both not associated'
             when max(in_s) = 1 and
                  max(max(in_m)) over (partition by col1) = 1
             then 'pair in srcTable, col1 in mytable'
             when max(in_s) = 1 and
                  max(max(in_m)) over (partition by col2) = 1
             then 'pair in srcTable, col2 in mytable'
             when max(in_m) = 1 and
                  max(max(in_s)) over (partition by col1) = 1
             then 'pair in myTable, col1 in srcTable'
             when max(in_m) = 1 and
                  max(max(in_s)) over (partition by col2) = 1
             then 'pair in myTable, col2 in srcTable'
             else 'solo pair'
        end)     
from ((select col1, col2, 1 as in_s, 0 as in_m 
       from tblSource
      ) union all
      (select cola, colb, 0 as in_s, 1 as in_m
       from myTable
      )
     ) x
group by col1, col2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=01bb6e8b14ccb0697a04614de64505dd) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
-- direct match
SELECT *
FROM myTable A
INNER JOIN tblSource B
    ON A.[colA] = B.[col1]
    AND A.[colB] = B.[col2];

WITH DataSourceHasDirectMatch AS
(
    -- does not have direct match
    SELECT A.[colA]
          ,A.[colB]
    FROM myTable A
    LEFT JOIN tblSource B
        ON A.[colA] = B.[col1]
        AND A.[colB] = B.[col2]
    WHERE B.[col1] IS NULL
)
SELECT 'ColAMatches', a.colA, b.col2
FROM myTable A
INNER JOIN tblSource B
    ON A.[colA] = B.[col1]
WHERE A.[colA] IN (SELECT [ColA] FROM DataSourceHasDirectMatch)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ColBMaches', a.[colB], b.col1
FROM myTable A
INNER JOIN tblSource B
    ON A.[colA] = B.[col1]
WHERE A.[colB] IN (SELECT [colB] FROM DataSourceHasDirectMatch)
```

[image]

Comment: the best for me is to keep the myTable intact since I have to loop through it and display the results in Excel with color-coding, can you modify it that way, please?

Comment: You don't want to select values from `myTable`?

Comment: this is practically a validation query, I am validating values in myTable against tblSource so I need to answer those 3 questions with this query. I just need to keep the order of the myTable the same so that I can quickly use the result in Excel

Comment: Can you show the expected result based on your input data?

Comment: I added the expected results